# how to extract data from mongodb into index.html served on nodejs server

Tags: node.js

Hello guys I have been working on my application for quite sometime now. I started with zero knowledge and I have been reading and working with this everyday for last couple of weeks now, And now I'm so close to a solution that I can taste it.

I hope someone could please help out a little. At this point I have done this:

- setup server
- setup mongodb
- finished small web scraper application
- Serve index.html to my server

Here is my code at this point:

```
var scraper = require(__dirname + '/scripts/scraper.js');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Listen for requests
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Index.html served on http://178.62.253.206:3000/');
});

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.collection("customers").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // view results in  console 
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

**Update:**

I thought I would use Embedded JavaScript as template engine.

How exactly can I update my code using ejs to get data from mongodb into the index page ?

Any Help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can use ```response.render``` to pass your backend data to the frontend, and use template params in your view file.

Comment: thanks for your reply guess I will have to read a little about this

Comment: all of this is way confusing so many options.. pheew